# javascript addEventListener in react js component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-manipulation

At first run the program is working correctly.
But after clicking on the sum or minus button the function will not run.

```
componentDidMount() {

if(CONST.INTRO) {

    this.showIntro(); // show popup with next and prev btn

    let plus = document.querySelector('.introStep-plus');
    let minus = document.querySelector('.introStep-minus');

    if (plus || minus) {

        plus.addEventListener('click',  () => {
            let next = document.querySelector(CONST.INTRO[this.state.introStep].element);
            if (next) {
                next.parentNode.removeChild(next);
            }

            this.setState({
                introStep: this.state.introStep + 1
            });

            this.showIntro();


        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As referenced in React documentation: [refs and the dom](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) the proper way to reference DOM elements is by using react.creatRef() method, and even with this the documentation suggest to not over use it:

> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.

I suggest that you manage your `.introStep-plus` and `introStep-minus` DOM element in your react components render method, with conditional rendering, and maintain a state to show and hide `.introStep-plus` DOM element instead of removing it inside native javascript `addEventListener` click

Here is a suggested modification, it might not work directly since you didn't provide more context and how you implemented the whole component.

```
constructor() {
  ...
  this.state = {
    ...
    showNext: 1,
    ...
  }
  ...

  this.handlePlusClick = this.handlePlusClick.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  if(CONST.INTRO) {
      this.showIntro(); // show popup with next and prev btn
  }
}

handlePlusClick(e) {
  this.setState({
      introStep: this.state.introStep + 1,
      showNext: 0,
  });
  this.showIntro();
});

render() {
  ...
  <div className="introStep-plus" onClick={this.handlePlusClick}></div>
  <div className="introStep-minus"></div>
  {(this.stat.showNext) ? (<div> NEXT </div>) : <React.fragment />}
  ...
}
```